# How to make custom filter in django

Tags: django, django-filter

I have made a webpage in which the user has four options to fill and send it to server. After that I have a filter in the database to give results to the webpage.

All the filters are optional.

Example: I have three arguments: `arg1 ,arg2, arg3` which are given by the user.

And write now issue is

```
x = SMS.objects.filter(Q(KPImessageId = arg1) | Q(subscriberId = arg2 ) |
                       Q(state = arg3))
```

The issue is, when I give all 3 arguments then it is working fine, but when I give only 2 arguments, then it is not able to sort and gives error.

I have to sort by these arguments, if `arg1` is present then sort by `arg1`. If `arg1` and `arg2` is present then sort by both arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your Q object dynamically in your view.

```
q=Q()
if arg1:
    q = q | Q(field1=arg1)
if arg2:
    q = q | Q(field2=arg2)
...
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(q)
```